# Windows code page 1252 able to handle non English Characters

Tags: unicode, globalization, codepages

We are in a situation where our program works on some machine and not on some others. We identified the problem as that of us using ANSI versions of GetTempPath; which fail in non English OSes. So far so good. However our code works on "some" computers and the results of a test app are inconsistent. It seems if the TEMP path has non english characters, say TEMP=E:/टेम्प, then on some computers GetTempPath returns E:/??? and then later attempting to open a file on that folder fails. Rightly so. Easy to fix - use unicode versions of the API.

But on some other computers it return the correct encoding, such that ultimately file opening succeeds.

I check the ACP on these computer - it is 1252. HOW IS 1252 able to encode non english characters?

It has become a topic of discussion - how was our program working all along? Such a bug should have been reported long ago etc.

Answer (score 0):

> HOW IS 1252 able to encode non english characters?"

Because codepage 1252 has various non-English characters in it.  See the full [character table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) on Wikipedia.  Note that `टे`, `म्`, and `प` are NOT present in 1252, which is why they end up as `?` when treated as ANSI.

Also, you should be using the **Unicode** version of API functions instead of the ANSI versions, then you wouldn't have this problem anymore.